STM32 and CC1200. The problem with reading the part number register
Good afternoon!
I'm trying to set up the cc1200 radio transceiver, I ran into a problem interacting with it via SPI, when trying to read the part number register, or any other, the answer is always 0xFF. I set the spi parameters according to the specification: 8bits, msb, 256 divider, cpol-low, cpha- 1 edge. The clock is set by default to sysclk 4 MHz.
I read the 0x8f register with this function after initializing the peripherals
`
int8_t readRegister(const uint8_t regAddr)
{
     uint8_t readCommand = regAddr | 0x80; 
        uint8_t statusByte = 0;
        uint8_t regValue = 0;
        
        CC1200_CS_LOW(); 
        
        HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi2, &readCommand, &statusByte, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
        HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi2, (uint8_t[]){0xFF}, &regValue, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);

        CC1200_CS_HIGH(); 

        return regValue; 
}

`
And at each reading, the response is 0xff.
Before that, I worked with at86rf, there were no problems.
Setting up the clock:
`
`void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  if (HAL_PWREx_ControlVoltageScaling(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_6;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}`

Setting up Spi:
`static void MX_SPI2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 1 */
  /* SPI2 parameter configuration*/
  hspi2.Instance = SPI2;
  hspi2.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi2.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi2.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi2.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi2.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_256;
  hspi2.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi2.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  hspi2.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
  hspi2.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SPI2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END SPI2_Init 2 */

}

Thank you in advance
I have tried different spi settings, as well as reading different registers when chip select was high or low, but the result was always 0xff

When writing driver for sensor, you must read the datasheet to understand how it is work first. I never use CC1200, but it only took me a minute to find out that in order to access the extended address of 0x8f, you need to write to register 0x2f first. See 3.2 SPI Access Types of documentation.

HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi2, (uint8_t[]){0xFF}, &regValue, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY); what exactly is the purpose of this line?
